# ¿Cómo leer una Base de Datos SQLITE desde la tarjeta SD?

Tags: android

Esta es la clase de la Base de Datos.
¿Qué cambios tengo que hacer leerla desde una pasta de la tarjeta SD ?

```
public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database name
    public static String DATABASE_QUESTION = "govti.db";
    // Current version of database
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUESTION = "GovTIBank";
    // All fields used in database table
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String CHOICE1 = "choice1";
    private static final String CHOICE2 = "choice2";
    private static final String CHOICE3 = "choice3";
    private static final String CHOICE4 = "choice4";
    private static final String CHOICE5 = "choice5";
    private static final String ANSWER = "answer";
```

No he logrado éxito en los cambios. No sé como es usado  "File.separator"
Me sale un error:

Error:(52, 31) error: method getExternalFilesDir in class Context cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Mi código se quedó asi:

```
public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String FILE_DIR = "/storage/269B-7026/datadb/";
    // Database name
    public static String DATABASE_QUESTION = "govti.db";
    // Current version of database
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database table name
...
    public MyDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir()
                + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator
                + FILE_DIR + DATABASE_QUESTION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.
Jose Bonfim

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase que extiende de [**SQLiteOpenHelper**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) tiene un constructor, en el cual puedes definir el nombre o la ruta a la cual deseas se guarde la base de datos.

Si deseas guardarla en el directorio de almacenamiento externo puedes usar [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), en el caso de tu clase serìa:

```
public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Constructor
    MyDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir()
            + File.separator + "/Database/" + File.separator
            + DATABASE_QUESTION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```